# fix JavaScript LoadMore button to load 5 items per page - Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

fix JavaScript `#LoadMore` button to load 5 items per page  - Django

i want show 5 item per once then user click on LoadMore button then it will load more 5 items

how to do that with js ?

html code :

```
{% for mobile in mobileforhome %}
<div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 800px;">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="Mobile/{{ mobile.slug }}"><img style="height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:6.5px;" src="{{ mobile.get_image }}" class="rounded float-right" alt="..."></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="card-body">
          <a href="Mobile/{{ mobile.slug }}"> <h5 class="card-title" id="primary_site_pages_app_name_control"> <b>{{ mobile.name }}</b></h5></a>
          <p class="card-text" id="font_control_for_all_pages">{{ mobile.app_contect|truncatechars_html:153|safe}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
         <small class="text-muted" id="date_post_control">{{ mobile.post_date}}</small>
         <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="{% url 'mobile' %}" id="tag_name_control">هواتف</a></small>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
{% endfor %}

    <!-- show more button -->
<div class="text-center mt-4">
  <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg loadMore" style="width:40%;color:white">Show More</a>
</div>

<!-- script controll the games ( show 6 game per page ) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
const thumbnails = $(".card-deck .card mb-3");
let visibleThumbnails = 0;

 function showThumbnailsUntil(index) {
   for (var i = visibleThumbnails; i <= index; i++) {
     if (i < thumbnails.length) {
        $(thumbnails[i]).addClass('visible');
        visibleThumbnails++;
     } else {
       break;
     }
   }
 }

 showThumbnailsUntil(2);

$(".loadMore").on("click",function(){
   showThumbnailsUntil(visibleThumbnails + 2)

   if(visibleThumbnails === thumbnails.length)
   {
       $(".loadMore").fadeOut(); //this will hide
       //button when length is 0
   }
})
</script>
<style>
 .card-deck {
   display: none;
 }

 .card-deck.visible {
   display: block;
 }
</style>
<!-- end script -->
```

this is my code but it don't work why ? (it's show button and you can press on it but it's do nothing ! it's show all items not 5 )

Comment: Hi , just change this `$(".card-deck .card mb-3");` to `$(".card-deck");` because you have hidden `.card-deck` not  `.card mb-3` so its working correctly but not able to remove hidden from `.card-deck`.

Comment: Okay so how i can remove hidden and show just 3 or 4 itms per once ?

Comment: Just change your selector `$(".card-deck .card mb-3");` to `$(".card-deck");` .Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/gd3qvpfm/1/)

Comment: i did that but the items don't hidden why ?

Comment: it's work when i add card-deck in new <div class="hidden"> then my design </div>

and in script i add hidden and work fine thanks